# What is the official way to add methods to the Generator.prototype?

Tags: javascript, iterator, mapreduce, generator

I am totally new to javascript generators. I have a lot of practical experience with Java Iterators and have done all softs of stuff with chains of Iterators in Java. But I am only just now discovering the generator function and yield and even yield* in javascript. I want to add a map and a reduce function somehow. Let's begin with map.

Yes, I have looked at [wu.js](https://github.com/fitzgen/wu.js/blob/master/wu.js), but to me that looks too much like a hack. Not opposed to re-wrapping in general, but I have the hunch that it could be doable more directly.

Here is what I have, first a range generator function:

```
function* range(start = 0, end = Infinity, step = 1) { 
    for(let i = start; Math.sign(step)*(end - i) > 0; i += step)
        yield i;
}

[...range(8,0,-1)] // > [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

That's cool. Now how can I add my map function? I discovered this:

[image: range.prototype > Generator {}]

It looks like this Generator {} is inviting me to stick some methods on it! So I can add map on that range prototype:

```
range.prototype.map = function*(fn) { 
    for(let x of this)
        yield fn(x);
}

[...range(8,0,-1).map(x => 2**x)] // > [256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2]
```

Wow! But if I want to follow a map with another map I need to say this first:

```
range.prototype.map.prototype.map = range.prototype.map
[...range(8,0,-1).map(x => 2**x).map(x => x-1)] // > [255, 127, 63, 31, 15, 7, 3, 1]
```

But I'd like to stick map on all Generators. When Array functions were not yet available on IE dinosaur edition 8, I did this:

```
if(!Array.prototype.map)
    Array.prototype.map = function(fn) { 
        var r = []; 
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
            r.push(fn(this[i], i, this);
    }
```

and that allowed me to work in IE dinosaur edition 8 just like in any decent browser. No quirky Util.arrayMap(...) function required. So I feel tempted to do just this now:

```
if(!Generator.prototype.map)
    Generator.prototype.map = = function*(fn) { 
        for(let x of this)
            yield fn(x);
    }
```

But uh oh, Generator is not a globally defined name like Array is! So I sneak in:

```
range.prototype.__proto__.map = function*(fn) { 
    for(let x of this) {
      yield fn(x);
    }
}

[...range(8,0,-1).map(x => 2**x).map(x => x-1)] // > [255, 127, 63, 31, 15, 7, 3, 1]
```

BINGO! I did it. To avoid using `__proto__` I can also do:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(range.prototype).map = ...
```

to the same effect.

But isn't there some more official way than to sneak through the side entrance with this `range.prototype._proto_` trick?

By more official way I mean say something straight forward such as

```
xxx.Generator.prototype.map = ...
```

where xxx is whatever module or some such the Generator class is defined in?

Comment: JavaScript is inherently prototype-based, but you're right, using `range.prototype.__proto__` [is not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to avoid all these warnings looming over the use of  `__proto__`.